# When resizing a gif with imagemagick, the image quality degrades

Tags: resize, imagemagick, gif, imagemagick-convert, resize-image

When resizing a gif with imagemagick, the image quality degrades

**Before resize:** [image]

After Resize:  [image]

I have tried below command:

```
convert input1.gif -coalesce -layers OptimizeFrame  -resize 309x550 -background transparent  -filter Lanczos -quality 100  output2222.gif
```

Comment: You have posted a JPEG and a PNG, whilst bemoaning GIF quality? Please post actual images (maybe using Google Drive or Dropbox) and please click [edit] and format your code as **code** rather than as a quotation. I mean to select your code with your mouse and click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **bold** and *italic*.

Answer (score 1):

Not surprised. You have a bad case of [banding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding) due to a slow gradient (shadow) with very few possible values due to the color quantization of GIF. If you convert the image directly from full-RGB to GIF, the conversion usually includes [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) to avoid such problems. But when you go from GIF to another GIF, the scaling entails pixel interpolation, which itself undoes the dithering. IM has a `-dither` option, but I can't make it do something useful in this case. Ditherting in IM is discussed [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#dither_error).